# how to add / remove entries from a .pickle file?

Tags: python, schema, pickle

i took over a project where .json files get parsed for further data analasys.
The json files are imported with a .pickle as schema:

```
import pickle
with open("json_schema.pickle","rb") as f:
  import_schema = pickle.load(f)

df_import = spark.read.format('json').schema(import_schema).load(fileName+'.json')
```

i need to edit the pickle to add / remove values to be read from the json.
How could i do this?

I am working with Python 3.8 in Spyder.

Comment: You don't edit a pickle file, it's just for storage. You can edit the object after it is loaded from the file.

Comment: Pickle files are not intended to be edited. You have 2 options: 1. Get hold of the program that created the pickle file and make your changes there. 2. Write some code that reads the schema from the pickle file, changes it, and writes it back out as a fresh pickle file.